# Parse.com doesn't push to android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse's latest SDK with android and i implemented it with my project which also using MaterialViewPager framework from github but for some reason, when i send a push from the web interface (dashboard), it says recipient found but "Push Sent 0".

Comment: have you enabled push services in parse.com settings

Comment: @Aakash: I believe you're talking about "REST push enabled" in the app setting menu. Yes, that option is enabled by default.

Comment: also have you subscribed your device to receive push notifications.

Comment: @Aakash, i don't really get that part as i didn't see that subscribe part on their sample app that they provided. I worked on Parse before like last year, we need to subscribe in order to receive push? But their sample app doesn't have the code for that included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of trying to solve a problem which i don't really know if it's from my app or parse itself as i tried so many things and wasted 2 weeks on that. I moved from parse to Google Cloud Messaging and it works fine. Push notification sent like instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to right but this are many issues with Parse Push for Android. I have experienced same kind of issue many times. Sometimes, push notification arrives late. There are many questions about these problems on SO. Unfortunately, there isn't any solution that works for these situations. The clear solution I found is to use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: That's weird. I created a test app and used their sample project and imported it to android studio and push works fine. It lead me to think that there are problems in my implementation but i checked so many times. I was also wondering maybe it's because i am using that framework that i mentioned, i was doing something wrong. It's not late, it doesn't sent out at all. :(

Comment: I was planning to use GCM but because need to implement server for that and kinda complicated for me... so i went with Parse... it works before for me... on my previous app that i worked with. That's is why i am thinking it might be a problem with the framework i am using, or i might not implemented it right, that's why i posted here for some guide.